# React this.props.params undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have problem passing `id` to my page with product, I tried everything and search answer but it still doesn't work.

Here is my index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import {render} from "react-dom";
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory} from "react-router";

import {Menu} from './components/Menu';
import {MainPage} from './components/MainPage';
import {DetailsProduct} from './components/DetailsProduct';

class App extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
        <Router history={hashHistory}>
            {/* <IndexRoute component={Menu}></IndexRoute> */}
            <Route path="/" component={()=>(<div><Menu/><MainPage/></div>)}></Route>
            <Route path={"product/:id"} component={()=>(<div><Menu/><DetailsProduct>asd</DetailsProduct></div>)}></Route>
        </Router>
        )
    }
}

render(<App/>, window.document.getElementById("app"));
```

And DetailsProduct
(page: http://localhost:8080/#/product/1)

```
import React from "react";    
export class DetailsProduct extends React.Component{

    render(){
        console.log(this.props.params); <-- this is undefined

        return(
            <h1>Product</h1>
        )
    }
}
```

**I came back here after a 3 years. Solution:**

Rendering components in this way is not a good solution:

```
<Route path={"product/:id"} component={()=>(<div><Menu/><DetailsProduct>asd</DetailsProduct></div>)}></Route>
```

But if you want to render a component like this (which I do not recommend) you have to add **props** as param argument to the function and then make restructuring on the component in which you want that props(**{...props}**)

```
<Route path={"product/:id"} component={(props)=>(<div><Menu/><DetailsProduct>asd</DetailsProduct></div>)}></Route>
```

Best solution is render route like this:

```
<Route path={"product/:id"} component={DetailsProduct}></Route>
```

and inside `DetailsProduct` you can render `<Menu />` or use `Switch` :

```
<Menu/>
<Switch>
    <Route exact path={"product/:id"} component={DetailsProduct}/>
    // Add any other routes you want here
</Switch>
```

Comment: What are you expect to see in `this.props.params`?

Comment: I didn't see you are passing props to <DetailsProduct> ?

Comment: <Route path={"product/:id"} component={DetailsProduct}></Route> it work now but i have to pass two components "Menu and DetailsProduct", Do u know how i can do this ?

Comment: How about import the <Menu /> component in <DetailsProduct> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use

```
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute} from 'react-router'
```

and

```
import {syncHistoryWithStore, routerReducer} from 'react-router-redux'
```

then I can get id by `this.props.params.id`

Answer (score 25):

I was also getting the same problem when I used `this.props.params.id`.

But when i tried to put `console.log(this.props)` in the component where I'm passing the id, it shows my id in **match** object so use:

```
this.props.match.params.id
```

to get the id (notice the added `match`).

Comment: Bump to why ^ works? is this based on react router version ?

Answer (score 24):

For me I was using the `render` method and finding that `this.props.match` was `undefined` in rendered components. This was the solution for me, you have to pass in `props`.

`this.props.match` will be `undefined` for:

```
<Route path='/users/:id' render={() => <UserDetail/>}/>
```

Do this instead:

```
<Route path='/users/:id' render={(props) => <UserDetail {...props}/>}/>
```

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func

Comment: props here can be a json object? I want to send props as well along with the match for id.

Comment: Thanks. Well spotted!

Answer (score 14):

replace this :

```
<Route path={"product/:id"} component={()=>(<div><Menu/><DetailsProduct>asd</DetailsProduct></div>)}></Route>
```

with :

```
<Route path={"product/:id"} component={DetailsProduct}></Route>
```

Comment: Wow Thanks it work, but how i can pass two components?

Comment: Why do you want to pass 2 components to one route ? that wouldn't be right! Or if you are looking for nested routes/components that is quite possible.

Comment: @Fawaz check my answer if you wanna still have multiple components in the route

Comment: how do i convert path which i am passing props as well `render={() => (
                                <HomeContent
                                    activeUser={this.props.activeUser}
                                    isGuest={this.state.isGuest}
                                    isSupp={this.state.isSupp}
                                 isReady={this.state.isReady}
                                />
                            )}`

Answer (score 4):

in `react-router-dom v6` you have to use **useParams()**.

like this:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const { id } = useParams();
```

this way you can access the id

Answer (score 3):

react router new version changed the route props object as the following:
this.props.match.params
instead
this.props.params

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match

Answer (score 3):

In the new version you have to use

```
useParams()
```

instead

```
this.props.params
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not using `react-router v4` but either `v2.x.x` or `v3.x.x`. In that case you should restructure your routes and you can pass multiple component using the [**`components`**](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#components-1) props as

```
   <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
              <IndexRoute components={{menu: Menu, mainPage: MainPage}}/>
              <Route path={"product/:id"} component={{menu: Menu, detail: DetailsProduct}}/>
         </Route>
    </Router>
```

And in the Menu Component 
Also the way you want it work is relatively very easy to do using `react-router v4`. In that case you can make use of prop render to provide a component and you could do the following with it

```
import {HashRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
...
<Router>
    <Route path="/" render={()=>(<div><Menu/><MainPage/></div>)}></Route>
    <Route path={"product/:id"} render={()=>(<div><Menu/><DetailsProduct>asd</DetailsProduct></div>)}></Route>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I had this code

```
<Route
    path={"/:url"}
    render={(routerProps) =>
        <BusinessApps
            {...routerProps}
            {...this.props}
            size={size}
        />
    }/>
```

I removed {...this.props} to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In React 6, you need to **useParams** like the following code when you pass it as a class-base:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
```

and for export write this:

```
export default (props) => (
<App
    {...props}
    params={useParams()}
/>
```

)

Finally you can use the params:

```
console.log(this.props.params);
```