# Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined]

Tags: react-router, jestjs

I am using react-router-dom to route my components and doing a test for one routed component.
My `App.js` has

```
<Route
     path="/register/:id"
     render={(props) => (
       <Details
         {...props}/>
     )}
></Route>
```

I tried to add the match into the component like this

```
const match = {
        params: {
            id: "123"
        }
    };
```

The `Details` component uses `this.props.match.params.id` in some functions, I don't know how these functions are called, but I get the error of

```
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined]
```

When I use

```
console.log(this.props.match)
```

I get

```
{ match: { params: { id: 'id' } } }
```

But when I use

```
console.log(this.props.match.params)
```

I get `undefined`.

**Update**

I think my way of passing the match parameter is wrong. Before I create a json object `posts` and pass that json object to the test component like this

```
mount(<Details {...posts}/>)
```

Then I change the way to

```
mount(<Details {...posts} match={match}>)
```

and it works.

Comment: Does this helps you?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144085/react-this-props-params-undefined/45144338

Comment: @prax No mine is different I think. I have updated my solution in the question.